# Notepad++ wildcard in find/replace

Tags: notepad++, wildcards

I have multiple lines with values like:

```
F9 23
F9 41
F9 32
F9 12
```

Those values change in many lines, I need change them to:

```
F9 23 text
F9 41 text
F9 32 text
F9 12 text
```

I try:

- find: `F9 .*.*.*`
- replace:

But i've no idea how i can replace and keep the original value after F9 and add a text after it.

Comment: Start by reading  - [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
 - [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^F9\h+\d+\K`
- Replace with: `text`     # a space then the text to be added
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  F9        # literally
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  \d+       # 1 or more digits
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Result for given example:**

```
F9 23 Text
F9 41 Text
F9 32 Text
F9 12 Text
```

Comment: @CaioCésar: You're welcome, glad it helps.